# A puzzle while learning Templates in C++

Tags: c++

```
template <class A,class B>
class H {

 public:
  A a;
  B b;
  void fac();
};

template <class B,class A> 
void H<B,A>::fac() {
}
```

What does  which follows H exactly mean ?
Since I declared `template <class B,class A>`, `<B,A>` seemed to be meaningless....

Can anybody help me ?? Thnx!!

Comment: For that to work, void fac() would have to be static.

Comment: I mean why can't I write void H::fac(){} instead of H<B,A>.??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no language rule preventing you from doing something like

```
template<class B> void H<B, B>::fac() {
}
```

and indeed it may be necessary for any explicit or partial specializations. However, since the vast, vast majority of template code is directly inline, it's really of little consequence.

For example:

```
template<class A, class B>
class H
{
public:
    A a;
    B b;

    void fac();
};
template<class A> class H<A, A> {
public:
    A a, b;
    void fac();
};

template<class A, class B> void H<A, B>::fac() {
}

template<class B> void H<B, B>::fac() {
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the correct answer, because no compiler seems to accept this code.

Comment: @UncleBens: Check my edit. My initial statement wasn't as clear as it should be, but I am entirely correct and my compiler happily accepts that code.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you put the template implementation in the template declaration itself:

```
template<class A, class B>
class H
{
public:
    A a;
    B b;

    void fac()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
};
```

However, [it is also possible to separate it out](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12):

```
template<class A, class B>
class H
{
public:
    A a;
    B b;

    void fac();
};

template<class A, class B>
void H<A, B>::fac()
{
    // Implementation
}
```

These two snippets mean the same thing. It's just how the C++ syntax works. Note that the identifier `H` in the first code snippet doesn't refer to an actual class; it refers to a *template class*, which is different from a normal class. `H` is the identifier of a *family* of classes that are similar but uses different template parameters. That's why you have to say `H<A, B>` and not just `H`.

Think about how it usually works for non-template classes:

```
class NonTemplateH
{
public:
    int a;
    short b;

    void fac();
};

void NonTemplateH::fac()
{
    // Implementation
}
```

You can see how they are similar.

Comment: this doesn't really answer his question.

Comment: @Nawaz: Huh? The OP asked "why can't I write void H::fac(){} instead of H<B,A>" and I specifically addressed that by saying that `H` refers to not one class but a family of classes (it's a template that can "generate" new classes). How is that not answering his question?

Comment: @In silico : no, he didn't ask that. he asked what does `H<B,A>` mean? He is implying that he is supposed to write `H<A,B>`, not `H<B,A>`?

Comment: @Nawaz: No. In a comment to the question the OP specifically asked "why can't I write void H::fac(){} instead of H<B,A>.??" The OP was wondering why `H` was not sufficient and had to write out the template arguments.

Comment: @Nawaz: As I understand, the question is why `<B, A>` is needed at all, since `H` is already known to be a template (which this answer doesn't seem to address).

Comment: @In silico : that is his in comment. But the topic asked something else. they are two different questions!

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, his comment said **"I mean why can't I write void H::fac(){}** instead of H<B,A>.?? " The OP was clarifying the question, and I addressed it. It wasn't two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Since I declared template `<class B,class A>, <B,A>` seemed to be
>   meaningless....

No, that is not meaningless. To understand that, consider this code:

```
template <class A,class B>
class H {

  template<class C> //note this line!
  void fac();
};
```

**Note:** Now, `fac()` is a **function template**. You've to define it like this:

```
 template <class A,class B> //as usual.
 template <class C>  //notice this line especially! (not so usual)
 void H<A,B>::fac()
 {
     //your code
 }
```

`H<A,B>` is needed because it tells the compiler that `A and B` are template parameters to the `class template H`, NOT to the function template `fac()`. `C` is the tempate parameter to the function template. Notice, I didn't write `fac<C>()` in the definition. Compiler automacally understands it.

Also, you can interchange the symbol A and B. But if you do this, then do this consistently.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between

```
template <class A, class B>
void H<A, B>::foo()
```

and

```
template <class A, class B>
void H::foo()
```

is that in the second case `foo` is a function template inside a non-template class `H`.

You can only use `H` without the template arguments at the class scope of `H`. That part of the definition still belongs to the global scope, where you have to explicitly say what `H` is.